# Cannot find Android studio 3.1 for mac

Tags: android-studio, react-native

Unfortunately I have updated my Android studio to 3.2.4 and since then, many issues occured.

I read from the 0.57 [Changelog](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)

> Android tooling has been updated to match newer configuration
>   requirements (SDK 27, gradle 4.4, and support library 27); building
>   with Android plugin 3.2 doesn't work due to the gradle scripts, so
>   please stay on Android Studio 3.1 for now

Now I can neither downgrade nor download version 3.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old versions are available in [Android Studio download archives](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive).